# Automating Backup and Shutdown

Tags: debian, shell-script, rsync, shutdown

I want to backup my entire internal hard drive files into an external hardrive and execute system shutdown once the backup is finished. The reason why I want to do that is to execute the backup during night and my pc's internal hard drive has run for more than 5 years.

A simple shell script of two lines would do it but it will be required to be executed as a super user, so the files copied to the external hard drive will be under root user and group.

```
# rsync -avh / /media/youssef/external/somedir/
# shutdown -P now
```

How to do that w/o superuser privilege?

Answer (score 1):

Without superuser you won't be able to do what you are asking. Typically you would only need to backup your /home/ folder. Some config files in /etc may be good to have backed up, but most of the rest of the root folder is for the os and shouldn't be backed up.